# Can't find MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
USE waterloo;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS waterloo;
CREATE TABLE waterloo
(
id              int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,   # Unique ID for the record
building        varchar(255) NOT NULL,                  # Name of building
floor           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Floor of building
gender          varchar(255) NOT NULL,                  # Gender of bathroom
location        int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Convenience of location of     bathroom
cleanliness     int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Cleanliness of bathroom
stalls          int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Number of stalls
noise           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Ambient noise
lines           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Length of lines at peak hours
graffiti        int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Amount of graffiti on the walls
PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'lines     int unsigned NOT NULL,       graffiti   int
>   unsigned NOT NULL          )' at line 11

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a boolean field "flushed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LINES` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You can still use it as a column name, though.  Just wrap it in backtics

```
`lines`
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines is a reserved word in MySQL -- add ticks around it and it should work.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

```
CREATE TABLE waterloo
(
id              int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,   # Unique ID for the record
building        varchar(255) NOT NULL,                  # Name of building
floor           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Floor of building
gender          varchar(255) NOT NULL,                  # Gender of bathroom
location        int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Convenience of location of     bathroom
cleanliness     int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Cleanliness of bathroom
stalls          int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Number of stalls
noise           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Ambient noise
`lines`           int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Length of lines at peak hours
graffiti        int unsigned NOT NULL,                  # Amount of graffiti on the walls
PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);
```

Hope that helps.